# array - float64 to array - ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python, am not aware of data types.

I want the output to be in the form

```
[[ 0.3120883 ]
 [ 0.36910208]
 [ 0.99886361]
 ..., 
 [-0.10729821]
 [ 0.08311962]
 [ 1.67302086]]
```

But currently my output is the form

```
[-0.13562086 -0.11107482  0.1600553  ..., -0.3161786  -0.23419835
  0.45029903]
```

How to convert it?

Answer (score 6):

You can [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it to `(-1,1)` to get the result in the form you want. Example -

```
narray = narray.reshape((-1,1))
```

Demo -

```
In [19]: import numpy as np

In [20]: narray = np.arange(10)

In [21]: narray
Out[21]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [22]: narray.reshape((-1,1))
Out[22]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Basically what you are doing is to change the shape of the array from something like - `(n,)` to `(n,1)` , you do this by using [`reshape()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) , in it you can pass `-1` as one of the arguments. As given in documentation -

> `newshape` : int or tuple of ints
>
> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. **One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.**

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to add a new dimension like this:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(10)
a
    array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

a[:,None]
    array([[0],
           [1],
           [2],
           [3],
           [4],
           [5],
           [6],
           [7],
           [8],
           [9]])

a[None,:]
    array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

I don't remember if `None` indexing is discouraged or not.